# Google Forms Quiz Score Data Format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, dataformat, google-form-quiz

New quizzing mode for google forms provides the scores in the form of a ratio with spaces in between (like this 5 / 7). However, the format of the cell is a number. So when I use dataRange.getValues(), I get only the first number (that is 5 in this example.) I tried setNumberFormat but received no permission error.

My goal is to somewhat get both numbers and actually complete the operation (5/7).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I just found an answer. I used getDisplayValues() instead of getValues().